# Error in retrieving data from Excel File

Tags: ssis

I have an excel file. I wanted to pull the data from excel file to SQL Server table. And the data is successfully transferred. In the excel file, I removed a text from one column named `Risk` from one row.The text was lengthy one. Now the package execution fails at the source ie from the excel file. The errors are shown as

```
[Audit [1]] Error: There was an error with output column "Risk" (100)
on output "Excel Source Output" (9). The column status returned was:
"DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".
```

and

```
[Audit [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "Risk"
(100)" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error
row disposition on "output column "Risk" (100)" specifies failure on
error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
information about the failure.
```

the error occurs when I remove this particular text from this row and when I clear the whole data except the column names and reenter a new data. And even if I replace the excel file with the same name and same column names but with different data.

Comment: when you say you "removed a text", exactly what did you do? did you open the excel file manually and delete the whole column, did you delete a single cell in that column, did you replace the column with a space?

Comment: I deleted a single cell in that column. and if the length of the cell is below 256, same error occurs. And it happens only to that particular cell only.

Comment: Or what is the correct method to import data from excel file to sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the excel is closed before you run the SSIS package. Plus try refreshing the meta data by opening the SSIS package, going to the columns section in the source and destination data flow items. There seems to be no other problems or you have described/observed it in the wrong way.

Comment: the error occurs when you replace the excel file with different data but same column name at first row or entering new data after clearing old data except the column name. thus the data pull fails.I had done by refreshing the meta data. the error is solved for time being. But once you deploy it on the server,do the above process. If fails, ou cannot refresh the package there at SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this...don't recall seeing it before in 10+ yrs of using SSIS. Google-ing found a solution. Right-click on the Excel connection>>Advanced Editor>>Input and Output Properties.  Open the "Output Columns" in the Excel Source Output treeview, and find the pesky column. Change the ErrorRowDisposition to RD_IgnoreFailure.

This got me part way - I had to go in and change the DataType property and the length afterwards to get it to work.  Then I put the ErrorRowDisposition back to fail and ran it only with the changed DataType and length, and it ran.

Play with these options and see if you can get it to work; I'm assuming that the data type change fixed it.